# How many characters long may an SQL Server SQL statement be?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What is the maximum length of an SQL statement in SQL Server? Does this length depend on the version of SQL Server?

For example, in

```
DECLARE @SQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Something' 
EXEC(@SQLStatement)
```

the `@SQLStatement` is allowed to be X characters long. What is X?

Comment: It depends on what the SQL statement is... or maybe I'm not understanding this question

Comment: I assume maximum number? Don't take comments above too seriously...

Answer (score 15):

It's going to be 65,536 times your network packet size, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Seems like this is the same at least since SQL Server 2005

Comment: And people downvoted the question thinking it was stupid and then Microsoft wouldn't really impose a length limit on a SQL statement.. HA. Good question Sohell Farahany.

Comment: @Evan - yeah, the question wasn't entirely clear, so I think most people didn't understand that he was asking about the maximum query size (at least that's what I think he is asking for)

Comment: @EricPetroelje, So what is the Maximum query size?

Comment: @Soheil - depends on your network packet size. For ethernet, 1500 bytes is typical, which would give you a max query size of better than 90MB.  So pretty huge.

Comment: @EricPetroelje, Thanks a lot, it was very kind of you.

Comment: @EricPetroelje - Network Packet Size may not be related to the ethernet packet size. According to MSDN documentation, it's the size of the TDS packages (default size is 4KB and is controlled by a configuration option). The size of the TDS packets can be larger than the size of the packets in the underlying protocol. 

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174503(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Verbatim from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

> 65,536 * Network Packet Size

What isn't clear, but which any sane person would immediately question, is what does "Network Packet Size" mean?

Network packet size, in this case, as expected, *does not* refer to physical size, since this would break the abstraction of end-to-end guaranteed delivery streaming protocol (TCP), but rather refers to packet size in the context of the Tabular Data Stream protocol used by SQL Server for communication.  According to the same documentation, the default size of a TDS packet is **4KB**.

Comment: 65,536 * 4096 = 268,435,456 bytes (if anyone wanted the actual number)

Answer (score 3):

The length of an SQL statement *should* be **as short as possible while maintaining human comprehensibility**.

Since parsing and compiling the SQL statement into an actual job for the DB engine is very fast, the length of the statement doesn't really matter to the parser. Of far more importance, especially for a hand-constructed SQL statement, is that a human can *maintain* that statement in the future.

Comment: Nice answer, but it seems the OP had a bit of a language barrier issue and actually meant to ask what the _max_ length of an SQL statement was. I've updated the question to reflect this, sorry for making you look crazy.

Comment: This is a false statement.  There are many use cases for dynamically generated queries. 'human comprehensibility' is quite subjective, but we can assume what you mean is understood in a couple of minute or less, which again, is not necessary.  I think your comment is probably only considering static or near static queries.  Maintainability is always a good to account for, but there are more contexts to consider.

Answer (score 3):

If your variable is defined as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` then it can be 2GB in size (remember that `NVARCHAR` uses two bytes for every character, compression aside). If you are approaching anywhere near this size, however, the length of your SQL statement is probably the least of your worries.

Comment: No no no, I Knew that NVARCHAR(MAX) is 2GB.
I meant the sql compiler, doesn't have any problem with running a 2GB statement?

Comment: Did you try it? Again, if your SQL statement is approaching this size, there are bigger problems IMHO.