# Bulk insert into SQL from a SOAP Request

Tags: sql-server, xml, soap, vbscript

Our current design is getting back an Http request text and parsing it by LoadXML. The XML data is being read by looping thru the nodes and inserting the data needed one at a time. Since I have a modification for this script, I would like to modify this using Bulk Insert. How could I directly do a bulk insert like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374134/bulk-import-xml-into-sql-server) but instead of having an XML File, i only have an XML Object.

```
Set http_request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http_request.open "POST", url, vbfalse
http_request.setRequestHeader "AUTHORIZATION", "Basic " & AuthInfo
http_request.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/soap+xml"
http_request.setRequestHeader "Content-length", Len(parameters)
http_request.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
http_request.send parameters
httpText = http_request.responseText

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.LoadXML httpText

Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

set Nodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes("//getRecordsResponse/getRecordsResult")

For Each node in Nodes
    *****Insert TO SQL*****
Next
```

Comment: Please include some code that shows how you are getting and parsing the XML, and what you are doing with it afterwards. As your question stands, it isn't even clear in what environment you want to do this.

Comment: I have included my VBscript code, not including the unimportant variables.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you must have a file on the server in order to use SQL Server's XML bulk insert. However, if you want to insert all the data in a single statement, you might want to consider using [`INSERT INTO ... VALUES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable
VALUES (
    ('Row1_Value1', 'Row1_Value2'),
    ('Row2_Value1', 'Row2_Value2')
)
```

Build up your list of values in the `For Each` loop. Something like this:

```
'probably needs to check each node if it is also an element
Dim length = xmlDoc.childNodes.Length
Dim rows(length), i, node
For i = 0 To length
    Set node = xmlDoc.childNodes(i)
    rows(i) = Array(node.getAttribute("Value1"), node.getAttribute("Value2"))
    rows(i) = "('" & Join(rows(i), "','") & "')"

    'It might be simpler to just build the string directly, instead of Array / Join
Next

Dim sql
sql = "INSERT INTO DestinationTable VALUES (" & Join(rows, ",") & ")"
```

Comment: I am considering the file if there is no other way. The Insert statement is a good idea, do you know the limit on how many characters can I append. The SQLstring will be appended with the values I am getting from the loop.

Comment: @Sid [It might be a valid concern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201354/how-many-characters-long-may-an-sql-server-sql-statement-be). But the default would appear to be `65,536 * 4KB`.